# How to filter out details from nested list having multiple dict inside in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a nested list having multiple dict inside it and wanted to find the website links, phone and email id details from the list.

## List:

```
lst_content = [[{'WEBSITE': 'https://www.fake.com/life/'}], [{'WEBSITE': 'http://www.fake.com/content/vb'}, {'123.123.3968 ': 'tel:123.123.3968 '}], [{'WEBSITE': 'https://fake.com/fsdds/'}], [{'WEBSITE': 'https://fake.com/svsd'}, {'SIGN UP': 'http://fake.com/vsdv'}, {'': 'mailto:abc.xyz@fake.com?subject=Inquiry from fake.com%20'}], [{'WEBSITE': 'https://fake.sdfs.fss.com/indi/search?onlineSiteId=0&activity_select_param=2&activity_keyword=grab&viewMode=list'}], [{'WEBSITE': 'https://www.fake.org/fdgbdfs/2021/tuesday'}, {'987.556.987': 'tel:987.556.2122'}], [{'WEBSITE': 'http://www.fake.org/afc'}, {'SIGN UP': 'https://www.fake.org/abc-registration-form/'}, {'': 'mailto:info@fake.org?subject=Inquiry from fake.com%20'}], [{'WEBSITE': 'https://www.fake.org/reopening'}, {'154.644.4200': 'tel:154.644.4200'}], [{'WEBSITE': 'https://fake.com/'}], [{'WEBSITE': 'https://fake.com/dfd/info.html'}], [{'WEBSITE': 'https://fake.org/garden-area-updates/'}, {'125.544.1948': 'tel:125.544.1948'}], [{'WEBSITE': 'https://www.fake.org/'}, {'(919) 949-1200': 'tel:(919) 949-1200'}], [{'WEBSITE': 'https://www.fake.org/'}, {'125.821.3222': 'tel:125.821.3222'}], [{'WEBSITE': 'https://www.fake.org/'}], [{'WEBSITE': 'https://www.fake.org/'}, {'212.962.5339': 'tel:212.962.5339'}], [{'WEBSITE': 'https://www.fake.com/moo'}, {'566.973.6847': 'tel:566.973.6847'}], [{'WEBSITE': 'https://fake.org/'}]]
```

## Code:

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval

web = []
phn = []
email = []

for web_lnk in lst_content:
    for k,v in web_lnk.items():
        try:
            match = literal_eval(re.search(r'addressLines.+?(\[.+?])', v).group(1))
            web.append(match)
        except:
            web.append("")
        
        try:
            tel = [x if (bool(re.search(r'[(]\d\d\d[)].\d{3}.\d{4}|[(]\d\d[)].\d{4}.\d{3}|\d{4}.\d{3}.\d{3}', x)) == True) else "" for x in v]
            phn.append(tel)
        except:
            phn.append("")
        
        try:
            mail = re.findall(r'([a-z]+@[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w.-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6})', v)
            email.append(mail)
        except:
            email.append("")
```

I am not able to get the required details, can anyone help me out in this.

## Expected Result:

```
    Website Phone   Email
0   https://www.fake.com/life/      
1   http://www.fake.com/content/vb  123 123 3968    
2   https://fake.com/fsdds/     
3   https://fake.com/svsd, http://fake.com/vsdv     abc.xyz@fake.com
4   https://fake.sdfs.fss.com/indi/search?onlineSiteId=0&activity_select_param=2&activity_keyword=grab&viewMode=list        
5   https://www.fake.org/fdgbdfs/2021/tuesday   987 556 2122    
6   http://www.fake.org/afc, https://www.fake.org/abc-registration-form/        info@fake.org
7   https://www.fake.org/reopening  154 644 4200    
8   https://fake.com/       
9   https://fake.com/dfd/info.html      
10  https://fake.org/garden-area-updates/   125 544 1948    
11  https://www.fake.org/   (919) 949-1200  
12  https://www.fake.org/   125 821 3222    
13  https://www.fake.org/       
14  https://www.fake.org/   212 962 5339    
15  https://www.fake.com/moo    566 973 6847    
16  https://fake.org/
```

[image]

*Note: All the data are dummy data and all the urls mentioned here started with 'fake', however original links will be different*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to go about it, but this should work.

```py
import re

web_dict = dict()
phn = []
email = []
index=0

for web_lnk in lst_content:
    index+=1
    for dictItem in web_lnk:
        for val in dictItem.values():
            if re.match(r'https?[/\w\.]*', val):
                if index in web_dict:
                    web_dict[index].append(val)
                else:
                    web_dict[index] = [val]
            elif re.findall('tel:', val):
                match = re.match(r'tel:\(?(\d{3})\)?[^\d]*(\d{3})[^\d]*(\d{4})', val)
                phn.append("{} {} {}".format(match.group(1), match.group(2), match.group(3)))
            elif re.findall('mailto:', val):
                match = re.match(r'mailto:([\w\.]+@\w+\.\w+).*', val)
                email.append(match.group(1))

web = [*web_dict.values()]
```

You might adjust regular expression as you see fit with the actual data. It shouldn't vary that much, but just in case.

Comment: It is almost as per expected output. But wherever there are 2 web links in single list, it should be in the same line separated by the comma. However, here 2nd link is coming in the next line. Example for: https://fake.com/svsd, http://fake.com/vsdv

Comment: @Biki I have edited it a bit, so you should know which email comes together now. I'll leave you to format what the outcome you want out of those lists.